# JS history.replaceState() error with multiple dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript

For giving the user the opportunity to navigate back to a filtered search result page I use history.replaceState() to set the correct url.

I do so everytime the ajax script is called to change the result page of the search by sending the new, correct url with the result set in a JSON string.

The responseText contains HTML and a container . I create a Dummy container (containerWithJsonString = document.createElement("div");) and put the responseText in there to be able to select the datatransfer via querySelectorAll('datatransfer').

I then fetch the well formatted url from that result by

```
dataFromAjaxCall=JSON.parse(containerWithJsonString.innerHTML);
makeNavigatableBackUrl(makeNavigatableBackUrl["url"]);

function makeNavigatableBackUrl(url) {
  history.replaceState({}, "", url);
}
```

I hand over a JSON string that has a well formatted string like this:
`https:\/\/www.domain.de\/?cmd=category&activePage=1&filter[156]=156&filter[170]=170&language=de`

But what I receive is after the JSON.parse is:

`https://www.domain.de/?cmd=category&activePage=1&amp;filter[156]=156&amp;filter[170]=170&amp;language=de`

When the user navigates back to this url, the $_GET array is resolved in PHP like this:

```
array (size=4)
'cmd' => string 'category' (length=8)
'amp;activePage' => string '1' (length=1)
'amp;filter' => 
  array (size=2)
  156 => string '156' (length=3)
  170 => string '170' (length=3)
'amp;language' => string 'de' (length=2)
```

Where I expect it to be

```
array (size=4)
'cmd' => string 'category' (length=8)
'activePage' => string '1' (length=1)
'filter' => 
  array (size=2)
  156 => string '156' (length=3)
  170 => string '170' (length=3)
'language' => string 'de' (length=2)
```

I asume I could easily work through the $_GET array to get rid of "amp;" in the keys, but is there a better solution to it? Can I change the behaviour or JSON.parse in a way that I can put a valid url in history.replaceState({}, "", url); instead?

Comment: then delete question

Comment: It is hard to tell what/where the problem might be. But given that not all  `&` are represented as `&amp;` indicates, that you concatenate the `&filter[156]=156&filter[170]=170&language=de` with the `https://www.domain.de/?cmd=category&activePage=1`, and that you might apply some escaping to it, before you concatenate it. Or that you try to do some manual replacing, and you only apply it once.

Comment: _"I asume I could easily work through the $_GET array to get rid of "amp;" in the keys, but is there a better solution to it?"_ - fix the part, that _introduced_ those `&amp;` in the first place ...? Can only guess that what you are passing to `makeNavigatableBackUrl` was _already_ the "wrong" version, but we don't see where from you are calling that.

Comment: Well. I found that the &amp; is added by a JSON.parse call. I will alter my question above  since it seems to be a problem with that JSON.parse() instead of history.replaceState()

Comment: Hard to believe that `JSON.parse` would alter the string. Type this into your JS console: `JSON.parse('"https:\/\/www.domain.de\/?cmd=category&activePage=1&filter[156]=156&filter[170]=170&language=de"')`. Looks like you're not carefully debugging each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `containerWithJsonString.innerHTML`, it gives you the HTML to render a `&`, that's why it's giving you `&amp;`

Use [containerWithJsonString.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead.

```js
const urlDiv = document.getElementById('url');
console.log(urlDiv.textContent);
```

```html
<div id=url>
https:\/\/www.domain.de\/?cmd=category&amp;activePage=1&amp;filter[156]=156&amp;filter[170]=170&amp;language=de
</div>
```

Also, I'm not sure why you're using `JSON.parse`. Does your HTML contain quotes around your string? If that's the case, the following example shows that.

```js
const urlDiv = document.getElementById('url');
const textContent = urlDiv.textContent;
console.log(JSON.parse(textContent));
```

```html
<div id=url>
"https:\/\/www.domain.de\/?cmd=category&amp;activePage=1&amp;filter[156]=156&amp;filter[170]=170&amp;language=de"
</div>
```